# How to modify a variable from a getter before passing in as a prop?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

was learning react and now trying my luck with vue. Some things are different and the following is one of it.

I use vuex and with it I get my state with a getter:

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["value"]),
    },
```

then I would like to pass is as a prop into a component:

```
<Card
                title="Updated"
                :value1="value.updated"
            />
```

In this case the variable `value` is a date and I would like to pass it in a ISO format and also split it, but the following is not working:

```
:value1="value.updated.toISOString().split("T")[0]"
```

Where can I modify my `value` variable to get the expected result? Is it the `<script>` section? But there my `value` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct just missed the quotes as T is also in double quotes

you need

```
:dt="dt.toISOString().split('T')[0]"
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hw3su91d/1/